# WHERE inside COALESCE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to return all `topics_i18n.content_i18n` which match both `id` and `language_code` but if the `id` exists but has no corresponding row in the other table that holds the `language_code` then return `topics.content`.

I've tried with 'COALESCE'

```
  SELECT
    topics.id,
    COALESCE (topics_i18n.content_i18n, topics.content) content,
    topics_i18n.language_code
  FROM topics
  LEFT JOIN topics_i18n
  ON topics.id = topics_i18n.topic_id
  WHERE section_id = $1 AND topics_i18n.language_code = $2
  ORDER BY position ASC
```

However this does not work, I feel like I need a `WHERE` inside the `COALESCE`?

```
  SELECT
    topics.id,
    COALESCE (topics_i18n.content_i18n WHERE topics_i18n.language_code = $2, topics.content) content,
    topics_i18n.language_code
  FROM topics
  LEFT JOIN topics_i18n
  ON topics.id = topics_i18n.topic_id
  WHERE section_id = $1 
  ORDER BY position ASC
```

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this?

Comment: can you make a fiddle of your tables and query, also what means doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the language subexpression from the `where` clause into the `on` condition and it should work fine. I guess that this is actually the business logic. Here is your query with the modification.

```sql
  SELECT
    topics.id,
    COALESCE (topics_i18n.content_i18n, topics.content) content,
    topics_i18n.language_code
  FROM topics
  LEFT OUTER JOIN topics_i18n
    ON topics.id = topics_i18n.topic_id 
   AND topics_i18n.language_code = $2
  WHERE topics.section_id = $1
  ORDER BY position ASC;
```